# CakePHP relational models

Tags: cakephp, model, relation

Basically i have 3 tables users , jobs and users_jobs.

users_jobs is id,job_id,user_id and is basically used for keeping track of what jobs a user has assigned.

Jobs can be assigned.unassigned by adding/removing entries in the users_jobs tables.

In terms of cakephp im struggling to understand how to model this.
So for i have a Job model that has the attribute

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'users_jobs',
        'foreignKey' => 'job_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id'
    )
);
```

My User model has the attribute

```
 public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Job' => array(
        'className' => 'Job',
        'joinTable' => 'users_jobs',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'job_id'
    )
);
```

In my JobsController.php i have the function unassign which is designed to unassign a user from a job. how can i modify the users_jobs table a remove the relation without remove the user or job ?

Comment: There shoud be an answer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006052/deleting-habtm-association-record

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have three fields on user_jobs:

status, user_id and job_id

Assuming your table user_jobs has one field status which is defines assigned or unassigned
 status=1 => Unassigned
 status=0 => assigned

Step 1: Create one methods in JobsController.php

```
    function userjobs($jobId, $userId, $assign = 1){
      # $assign is 1 means true and 0 means unassigned

      # if you want to assign a job to user
      $data['UserJob']['user_id'] = $userId;
      $data['UserJob']['job_id']  = $jobId;
       App::import('model','UserJob');
       $UserJob = new UserJob();


      if($assign == 1){
        $UserJob->save($data);
      }else{
        $UserJob->updateAll(
                   array('UserJob.status'=>1),
                   array('UserJob.user_id'=>$userId,'UserJob.job_id'=>$jobId));
      }

    }
```

Step 2: call this method on ajax.

It will do the desired thing.